# How to return a value label by indexing label position

Tags: stata

Suppose I have a variable named MyVar with value labels defined like this:

```
0  Something
1  Something else
2  Yet another thing
```

How do I obtain the *second* value label (i.e. "Something else")? **Edit:** Assume that I do not know *a priori* what the factor values are (i.e. I do not know the minimum value label, and the factor values may increment by numbers other than 1, and may increment unevenly).

I know I can obtain the label corresponding to the *value* of 2:

```
. local LABEL: label (MyVar) 2, strict
. di "`LABEL'"
Yet another thing
```

But I want to obtain the label corresponding to the *position* of 2 in the value label list:

```
. <Some amazing Stata-fu using (labeled) variable MyVar and the position 2>
. di "`LABEL'"
Something else
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the labels into a vector in Mata.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. mata 
------------------------------------------------- mata (type end to exit) --
: st_vlload("origin", values = ., text = "")

: values
      1
   +-----+
 1 |  0  |
 2 |  1  |
   +-----+

: text
          1
   +------------+
 1 |  Domestic  |
 2 |   Foreign  |
   +------------+

: text[2,1]
Foreign

: end
```

That could be the hard core of a program to do something with them. Dependent on what you want to do, the answer could be expanded. It's also up for grabs whether you start with a variable name or a value label name.

EDIT: Here is a quick hack at a program to return the j th value label. You present a name which by default is taken to be a variable name; with the `labelname` option it is taken to be a value label name. Not much tested.

```
  *! 1.0.0 NJC 7 Oct 2014 
  program jthvaluelabel, rclass  
  version 9 
  syntax name , j(numlist int >0 min=1 max=1) [labelname] 

  if "`labelname'" == "" {
      confirm var `namelist' 
      local labelname : value label `namelist'
      if "`labelname'" == "" { 
          di as err "no value label attached to `namelist'"
          exit 111
      }
  } 
  else { 
      local labelname `namelist' 
      capture label list `labelname'  
      if _rc { 
          di as err "no such value label defined"
          exit 111  
      }
  } 

  mata: lookitup("`labelname'", `j') 

  di as text `"`valuelabel'"' 
  return local valuelabel `"`valuelabel'"'  

  end 

  mata: 

  void lookitup (string scalar lblname, real scalar j) { 
  real colvector values 
  string colvector text 
  real scalar nlbl 
  string scalar labels 

  st_vlload(lblname, values = ., text = "")

  nlbl = length(text) 

  if (nlbl == 1) labels = "label" 
  else if (nlbl > 1) labels = "labels" 

  if (nlbl < j) { 
      errprintf("no such label; %1.0f %s, but #%1.0f requested\n", 
          nlbl, labels, j) 
      exit(498) 
  } 
  else {
      st_local("valuelabel", text[j]) 
  }

  }

  end
```

Some examples:

```
 . sysuse auto, clear
 (1978 Automobile Data)

 . jthvaluelabel foreign, j(1)
 Domestic

 . jthvaluelabel foreign, j(2)
 Foreign

 . jthvaluelabel foreign, j(3)
 no such label; 2 labels, but #3 requested
 r(498);

 . jthvaluelabel make, j(1)
 no value label attached to make
 r(111);

 . jthvaluelabel origin, j(1) labelname
 Domestic
```

Posting code here is occasionally a little difficult. The code delimiters aren't always respected. The real program on my machine is indented more systematically than is evident from the version above.

Comment: Nick, how would I know that MyVar had the label "origin"? (See my revised question, and appologies for my earlier lack of clarity.)

Comment: You wouldn't; that is just the one set of value labels in the auto dataset.

Answer (score 4):

You want to nest a couple of [extended macro functions](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/pmacro.pdf#pmacro) like [matryoshkas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll):

```
clear 
set obs 3
gen x=_n-1
label define xlab 0  "Something" 1  "Something else" 2  "Yet another thing"
lab val x xlab

levelsof x, local(xnumbers)
di "`:label xlab `:word 2 of `xnumbers'''"
```

Working from the end of the last line to the front. The local xnumbers produced by `levelsof` contains the distinct levels of x from smallest to largest: 0 1 2. Then you figure out what the second word of that is local is, which is 1. Finally, you get the label corresponding to that numeric value, which is "Something else".

Comment: The label of the `j`th value is the `j`th value label if and only if all of the first `j` values have labels attached.

Comment: @NickCox That is a fair point. I often have variables that are numeric with a top-coded value of that is labeled "x+" or ">=x", where that is the only label.

Comment: Dimitriy, how would you know that `x` has the value labels `xlab`? (Apologies for not clarifying... I have edited my earlier question.) What if you want to select the 2nd position of the value labels of a variable that someone handed your program... (i.e. you aren;t sure if there are value labels or not)

Comment: @Alexis I would probably use Dr. Cox's `labvalclone` from `labutils` suite to clone the value labels from all the variables and label the variables with the clones. Then I would know the name for sure. I generally like for the labels to have the same name as the variables. A less draconian alternative would be to use Daniel Klein's `labellist`.

Answer (score 1):

I cobbled together a nice solution from Nick's and Dimitriy's answers and comments (the application is for a function outputting a line of a table, in a section and the user has specified that they want labels for `groupvar` for the position `index`):

```
local labelname : value label `groupvar'
mata: st_vlload("`labelname'", values = ., text = "")
mata: st_local("vallab", text[`index'])
local vallab = substr("`vallab'",1,8)
```

Then the program carries on using the local `vallab`.

Comment: This would be a very good way to build in some code to a larger program, although there is no checking, so some graceless error messages are likely if assumptions are wrong. Note that the column subscript isn't needed in accessing the particular element of `text[]`, which is a column vector any way.

Comment: @NickCox You are right about the checking. There is implicit checking elsewhere in the application, but this is a fragility. Also I have edited to use the one-dimensional indexing of mata. :)